# How can I hide a django label in a custom django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, widget

I have a custom form that creates a hidden input of a field:

```
class MPForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super(MPForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs )
        self.fields['mp_e'].label = "" #the trick :)

class Meta:
    model = MeasurementPoint
    widgets = { 'mp_e': forms.HiddenInput()  }
    exclude = ('mp_order')
```

I have to do this little trick to "hide" the label, but what I want to do is remove it from the form. I create the form like this:

```
forms.MPForm()
```

Comment: As an aside, don't forget the trailing comma in your `exclude` tuple. It should be `exclude = ('mp_order',)`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend removing the label as it makes the form inaccessible. You could [add a custom CSS class](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2487/) to the field, and in your CSS [make that class invisible](http://xhtml.com/en/css/reference/visibility/).

**EDIT**

I missed that the input was hidden so accessibility isn't a concern.

You can render the form fields directly in your template:

```
<form ...>
    {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.label }} {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Comment: It is just a control hidden input, I do not need the label, I am using this hidden input as a token.

Comment: Okay I missed that the field was a hidden one. Sorry, I'll edited the answer above.

Comment: I think this is the best way of doing it, but they should implement a way of deleting labels in a form...

Thanks!

Comment: Works with Django 2.0 as well.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question IMO

Answer (score 20):

Now,(my django version is 2.1.4), you can solve in this way -> Edit forms.py file:

```
password = forms.CharField(label=False)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use the `form.as_p` or `form.as_table` method, Django shouldn't display the labels for your hidden fields anyway, so there's no need to change the label in your `__init__` method.

```
{{ form.as_table }}
```

If you are [customizing the form template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields), you can use the `field.is_hidden` attribute to check whether the field is hidden.

```
{% if field.is_hidden %}
   {# Don't render label #}
{% endif %}
```

Alternatively, you can [loop over hidden and visible fields separately](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields), and omit the label for hidden fields.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the form without any customization, just changing thing in form.py, but it looks like it is impossible to do that

Comment: As I said above, **Django won't show the label for hidden fields by default**. You don't need to change the label in your `__init__` method. If the label is being displayed, then you're doing something in your view or template that you haven't included in your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! 
This solution works. It is a pity that it cannot be done in the settings. This solution is a bit of a way around ...

Answer (score 4):

i found this useful and it works for me!

```
class CustomForm(forms.Form):
class Meta:
    ...  #other properties such as model, fields, widgets and help text
    labels = {
       'comment' : '',
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to give False and it will work:

```py
self.fields['mp_e'].label = False
```

django version: 2.2

Comment: it doesn't work, you're setting a new value to label

Comment: as noted by ziyad akmal, you need to add False to the 'label' option in your form definition (look in forms.py)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your forms.py file and
add label = false

as
below

```
name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Enter Name *'}), label=False)
```

Comment: label=False prints False as label.  This does not hide the label name

Comment: I think he meant `label=""`

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you just need to add the mp_e field to the exclude tuple under the meta class. is this not what you need?

```
class MPForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        super(MPForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs )

    class Meta:
        model = MeasurementPoint
        exclude = ('mp_order','mp_e')
```

Comment: No, I need a hidden input, what I do not need is the label in front of it.